# Show "Details Pane" only if a certain extension is in the folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I want explorer to behave such that if I am browsing a folder containing a file of a certain kind (for example a list of extensions), then the View->Details Pane will be enabled. If there is no file of that type, Details Pane will not show. Any way to make this happen?

Comment: File Explorer does not have this feature at this time.  The closest you can come is setting the folder view options to a folder type.

Comment: i am willing to consider modifications